# Does working on ubuntu in flash drive leave a trace on Hard Drive having Windows installed in it

Tags: hard-drive, usb-creator, flashcache

I have installed ubuntu in Flash drive with a persistence space of 200 MB. If i boot my laptop from flash drive having ubuntu installed and do net surfing and download files on internet , will it leave any trace in form or temp file or any other manner in the hard drive of my laptop. The hard drive has Windows 7 installed on it

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

A LiveCD/LiveUSB does not need a hard disk or even a writable media installed to run properly.

So your Windows 7 partitions are safe and won't be touched at all.